# Ruby on Rails - Set how many image show per page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, each

In my application, I have `Post` & `Slide` models. `Post` `has many :slides`, and I use `nested_forms` to add **slides to posts**.

What I have now is, on the **post page** I can show all the `slides` that belong to the post.

*I use `@post.slides.each do |slide|`*

By using `#each` I show all the slides on same page. What I want to achieve is to be able to set how many `slides` I want to show per page.

*Example:* A post has **20 slides**, and I set **5 slides** each page. It only show 5 slide per page with a Next button to the next 5 etc and the URL would for instance be `domain.com/posts-title/1`, `domain.com/posts-title/2` ect.

*(I have already the next button)*

**any method without using pagination is much appreciated**

Comment: Paginate the `@post.slides` in your controller action

Comment: You might want to look into kaminari, the paginator (https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari) you will have to update your post page route with a `page` parameter, and then use `@post.slides.page(params[:page]).per(5).each do |slide|` to iterate over the slides.

Comment: `will_paginate` could be used for pagination. Alternatively you could use offset and limit on queries to get the desired output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> gem 'kaminari', '0.16.3'

Define an before_action for set set_peginate into your controller.

```
  before_action :set_peginate
```

define method for set_peginate

```
  def set_peginate
    @per_page = params[:per_page].to_i <= 0 ? PER_PAGE : params[:per_page].to_i
    @page     = params[:page].to_i <= 0 ? 1 : params[:page].to_i
  end
```

you need to define one static variable to set default per page record size.

use kaminari method for use paginate

```
 @slides = @post.slides.page(@page).per(@per_page)
```

now your view will get only PER_PAGE record ex: PER_PAGE = 20

for passing paginate method you need to embedd below code inside you .erb page

Comment: Thanks @Darpan. Is it any way I can get the `total_pages` count for pagination to be able to make the **Next** & **Prev** button?

Comment: this gem will add total page and also add next and prev button to your view.

Comment: thanks. I have used `Kaminari gem` before. I don't want to use its `paginate` in that view and want to make something my own.

Comment: its good :), i have created this without gem.
flag   = page <= 1 ? 0 : 1
page   = page <= 1 ? 0 : page - 1 ##durty patch
offset = (LIMIT * page) + flag

and jus add .limit(LIMIT).offset(offset)

Comment: is any way I do it without using `Pagination`, since `pagination` adds a `?page=2` *param* and I am more looking for a `/2`. Hope you can help me out

Comment: Could you please add the new solution as a answer please :)

Comment: yes for that you need to change your controller action routes and you will get requested page into your controller as params
ex:   get 'xyx/:page', to: 'my#index', as: :xyz,
here page will be any int value so hope it will helpful for you :)

Comment: Thanks for your help @Darpan